# Spring boot app in another project from controller class

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I want to know if I can keep my Spring boot class in Project A and my controller and services in Project B and invoke the end-points from Project A? The reason to do this is because I want to give Project A (which has dependency of Project B) an option to extend my controller and services to override any method.

Comment: You can try Microservices architecture. http://www.springboottutorial.com/creating-microservices-with-spring-boot-part-1-getting-started

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a common practice to have your starter in a project and the libraries in another (spring projects are a good example for it).

1. it is better to have them separated in 2 repositories :faster build, version management, separation of responsibility between team members etc.
2. Build the project with the libraries (A)
3. Project with the starter (B) will have a dependency to project A
4. In general, it is recommended to have a configuration in project A with @ComponentScan and project B should import the configuration.

If the beans are scanned from project A, you will have access to all endpoints and services.

Comment: Hi Adina, saw an example from Spring at https://spring.io/guides/gs/multi-module/
Are you talking about this approach? In the example they defined the controller and Spring boot class the same. But I want to move the controller part to other project as well. Is that possible?

Comment: That approach is used to have a common library between modules inside the same project. You want to have a library that can be reused between 2 different projects. Example https://github.com/spring-projects they are 2 different repositories - spring-framework have the libraries and spring-boot have actual implementations. Spring-boot depends on spring-framework via maven dependency.